# Function / alias that opens all files from glob expression

Tags: linux, bash, gnome

I'm trying to write a terminal function / alias that opens all files from whatever glob expression I want (eg, all files with the same extension).

I've tried to use both `find -exec` and `find | xargs`

This works:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.eps' -exec gnome-open {} \;
```

this function (sourced on ~/.bashrc) only opens one file:

```
openall () { find . -type f -name "$1" -exec gnome-open {} \; ; }
```

I also tried the xargs route (which works, when written in the terminal):

```
$ find . -iname "*.eps" -print0 | xargs -0 gnome-open ;
```

which again only opens one file, while one this works:

```
$ find . -iname "*.eps" | xargs -n 1 gnome-open ;
```

the function (again, sourced on ~/.bashrc) doesn't:

```
openall () { find . -iname '$1' | xargs -n 1 gnome-open ; }
```

as it returns:

```
Usage: gnome-open <url>
```

I think I'm doing something wrong while passing the arguments, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Are you remembering to quote the glob when calling the function? You don't want it expanded before the call.

Comment: perhaps double quotes? `openall () { find . -iname "$1" | xargs -n 1 gnome-open ; }`

Comment: @ooga well, don't I feel stupid. I guess there's no way not to have the glob expand without using the quotes, is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not showing how you *call* the functions that are failing.

```
openall () { find . -type f -name "$1" -exec gnome-open {} \; ; }
```

should work, but you need to quote the argument:

```
openall "*.eps"
```

Otherwise, the shell expands the pattern *before* calling `openall`, and your function picks only the first of the expanded arguments.

```
openall () { find . -iname '$1' | xargs -n 1 gnome-open ; }
```

Here you are using single quotes. This ignores all arguments and finds only files with the literal name `$1`.

---

Maybe it's simpler to provide just a suffix instead of a pattern? That avoids quoting:

```
openall () { find . -type f -name "*$1" -exec gnome-open {} \; ; }
```

Note the `*` before `$1`. Call it like this:

```
openall .eps
```

Comment: Why not just `openall() { for i in "$@"; do gnome-open "$i"; done; }`, which can be called as `openall *.eps`?

Comment: Because the question calls `find` to search in subfolders, while the shell pattern expansion works only in the current directory.

Comment: Well, if [`globstar`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) is enabled, `openall **/*.eps` will search subdirectories, too.

Comment: And `**/*.eps` is an improvement over `"*.eps"`? Requires one character more to type, and depends on a shell option being set.

Comment: And what if you don't want to search recursively?

Comment: I gave an answer to the question, not to what-ifs. The question calls `find`.